# Android: Gradle build task adds a final keyword to a method

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I'm experiencing something strange, that never happened to me before.
This is simple class that extends an Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

It is a library module, than I try to extend it from an application module:

```
public class MyApp extends MyApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("MyApp", "Application created");

    }
}
```

Now when compiling with `minifyEnabled=true` I'm getting strange result:
In library module class get changed to (note the **final** keyword):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    MyApplication() {
    }

    public final void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And this causes compilation error, since MyApp cannot override a final method.
Did someone faced this issue?
Thanks in advance.
Happens only with minify enabled. Class MyApplication is added to proguard-rules as exception.
**Happens only on Gradle > 7.1.3. Reverting to 7.1.3 fixes the cause.**